# Python [ mod_wsgi ] how to gather up all of the mysql results into an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

via cli:

```
[root@localhost 0]# python test13.wsgi
(1, 'aaaaaa')
(2, 'sdsdfsdfsd')
(3, 'dsfsdfasdfsdf')
(4, 'sdgsdgsdfsa')
[root@localhost 0]#
```

via apache :

```
(4, 'sdgsdgsdfsa')
```

script code:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "root",
                        passwd = "",
                        db = "aaa")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("select * from bbb limit 10")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for i in range(numrows):
    row =  cursor.fetchone()
    print row
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    return [repr(row)]
```

i would like to simply put all those rows into an array like in php 
and then do a print_r() equivalence in python compared to php.

so that what prints in the apache is everything rather than just the
last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
for i in range(numrows):
    row =  cursor.fetchone()
```

Sets `row` to the result of `cursor.fetchone()` `numrows` times. It doesn't make a list.

You probably just want to write `rows = cursor.fetchall()`.

Also, if you're trying to write a simple (or complex) webapp with Python, I would consider looking at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

Comment: well this works but don't i need it to be in an array so i can select which array to print ? this is what i am getting.. ((1, 'aaaaaa'), (2, 'sdsdfsdfsd'), (3, 'dsfsdfasdfsdf'), (4, 'sdgsdgsdfsa'))
 how can i selectively print one of them ?

Comment: @PythonNewbie: Read a Python tutorial before jumping into WSGI.

Comment: i will choose to stay away from flask, django, etc, because i think soon as i figure a way to get some stuff from mysql and then do a php-apc equivalence memory caching, i will no longer need much to design a web page.

Comment: sounds good, i guess the next question will be how to print a specific array.